# React auto scroll to bottom of a div

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

**So currently I have this issue, I am in react**
[image: Issue Gif]

**I want when the page load, it auto scrolls to the bottom of the messages box**

This is my current code : https://sourceb.in/GU4IOYtB9H

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const Messages = ({ messages }) => {

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null)

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom()
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map(message => <Message key={message.id} {...message} />)}
      <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
    </div>
  )
}
```